# working of linkbutton in repeater

Tags: c#, repeater, asp.net-4.5

I used a linkbutton in repeater which on click shows data in a label.Now i want that clicking again the same linkbutton hide that data,means same button for showing and hiding data.
there is a database with a table which contains ques-description,date,sub. by and ans.

On page load only question appears.

Now this is the design code:

```
protected void Repeater1_ItemCommand(object source, RepeaterCommandEventArgs e)
       {  
            if (e.CommandName == "showanswers")  
            {  
                Control control;  
                control = e.Item.FindControl("date");
                if(control!=null)
                control.Visible = true;
                control = e.Item.FindControl("subby");
                if(control!=null)
                control.Visible = true;
                control = e.Item.FindControl("ans");
                if(control!=null)
                control.Visible = true;
            }
```

And this is the html  code i used:

> 

```
<asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server"  
            onitemcommand="Repeater1_ItemCommand">

            <ItemTemplate>
                <table>
                        <b>Question<%#Container.ItemIndex + 1%>:</b><%#Eval("qstdsc") %><br />
                        <asp:linkbutton ID="Button1" Text="Ans." commandname="showanswers" runat ="server" /><br />
                    </table>
                <table>
                        <asp:Label id="date" Text='<%# Eval("qstdat")%>' Visible="false" runat="server"/>
                    </table>
                    <table>    
                    <asp:Label id="subby" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("qstsubby")%>' Visible="false" />
                       </table>
                <table>
                         <asp:Label id="ans" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("qstans")%>' Visible="false" />
                </table>

             </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:Repeater>
```

But i don't know how to hide data again clicking the same linkbutton.
Is it possible with a single button?

Comment: Paste your code here. Before you do that, read [faq] and [ask] a couple of times..

Comment: Yes, but you should show us what you have tried. What hinders you to check if the label is visible and hide/show it accordingly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What hinders you to check if the label is visible and hide/show it accordingly?

```
protected void lnkBtnShowDataLabel_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    lblData.Visible = !lblData.Visible;
}
```

Comment: Since you have shown now that you're using the repeater's `ItemCommand` event, you can use your code and replace `control.Visible = true;` with `control.Visible = !control.Visible;`. This should just switch visibility.

Comment: @user2069465: When do you databind the repeater, is it possible that you're doing it on **every** postback? Does your code work, so can you make them  visible at all? Is the `Repeater1_ItemCommand` triggered at all, have you set a breakpoint there?

Comment: oh yes sir now it's working after using postback :p Thank you so much sir :)